# web driver c# xpth\css Element identifications

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have this code in html:

```
<br>
input name="commit" value="Apply" style="" type="submit" 
<br>
```

And that's what I wrote in the web driver code in

```
heredriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='commit'][4]")).Click();
or
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#new_reduction > input[name="commit"]")).Click();
```

I get the following error message:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='commit'][4]"}

Addition `html` from comment:

```
<form class="new_reduction" id="new_reduction" action="/admin/reductions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="mZHoKI82s1fk7w2FCsqbNiGM9kJyE45dzwV3w2cuFzniZe6lDDum9‌​LDNxAsIokpxH90b/cFxq‌​Cil5EMvuvBwA==">
        Cou‌​pon Code: 
    <input value="3167050" type="hidden" name="reduction[order_id]" id="reduction_order_id"> 
    <input value="81069" type="hidden" name="reduction[web_user_id]" id="reduction_web_user_id"> 
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code"> 
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Apply"> 
</form>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='commit'][4]"}

Comment: Is your element in `iframe`?

Comment: The html markup should be fixed on this. When you have to start using [4] on your xpath, your automation becomes very brittle. That input should have an id="fieldName"  and should not be wrapped around <br> elements. You can make this work but one dev change in this area will probably kill your automation. If i was forced to write it this way, I would probably look at preceding-sibling or following-sibling to incorporate that so it is less brittle.

Comment: @DanielShmayovich take a look at @Narendra's comment. Some of those selectors look correct unless you've given us something wrong. So you're either in an `iframe`, `frame`, or maybe your driver is just on the wrong window.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the index

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='commit']")).Click();
// or
driver.FindElement(By.Name("commit")).Click();
```

Comment: post the full html

Comment: <form class="new_reduction" id="new_reduction" action="/admin/reductions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="mZHoKI82s1fk7w2FCsqbNiGM9kJyE45dzwV3w2cuFzniZe6lDDum9LDNxAsIokpxH90b/cFxqCil5EMvu0vBwA==">Coupon Code:
<input value="3167050" type="hidden" name="reduction[order_id]" id="reduction_order_id">
<input value="81069" type="hidden" name="reduction[web_user_id]" id="reduction_web_user_id">
<input type="text" name="code" id="code">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Apply">
</form>